# i18n within my own twig extension

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I use twigs i18n in my own twig extension?

This is what I have right now: http://pastebin.com/yNhHuC6C  but need to use i18n within.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You surely have a service definition of this twig extension, something like:

```
    <service id="test_post_extension" class="Test\PostBundle\Twig\Extensions\TestPostExtension">
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
    </service>
```

You can inject any other service in your's, like the `twig.extension.trans` service.

The xml becomes:

```
    <service id="test_post_extension" class="Test\PostBundle\Twig\Extensions\TestPostExtension">
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
        <argument type="service" id="twig.extension.trans" />
    </service>
```

Your TestPostExtension class will then receive a `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension` as first argument of its constructor:

```
namespace Test\PostBundle\Twig\Extensions;

class TestPostExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function __construct(Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension $transExt) {
        $this->transExt = $transExt;
    }

     // some stuff
}
```